# Парсинг атрибута svg через js

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть строка

```
transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) translate(50,50)"
```

Как из нее вытащить параметры `translate`, изменить и вернуть обратно?

Comment: Можно полный код svg и подробнее вопрос?

Comment: По идее, вы можете вытащить атрибут `transform` у элемента по `id` или классу, что-то вроде `var transform = document.querySelector("#svg-id");` , но потом вам нужно эту строку распарсить и найти слово `translate`, присвоив его переменной.

Comment: Moжно просто считать svg-контент в строку - сделать replace, и в img.src  записать посредством data-протокола.

Answer (score 3):

Увеличиваем все циферки на 10:

```js
const transform = "matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) translate(50, 60, 70 ,80,90)";
const re = /translate\(((\d+\s?,?\s?)+)\)/;
transform_params = transform.match(re)[1];
console.log(
  transform
    .replace(re, `translate(${
       transform_params.split(',').map(t => +t+10)
    })`)
);
```